# How to drop (delete) consecutive values in a Dataframe

Tags: python, list, numpy, performance, diff

I have a dataframe with a column that has 0 Values. I wish to find those 0 values and check if till the end they are 0, drop only those at the end and not in the middle.

this is how the Data in `secondary_df` looks like:

```
      DSCD        date    year    month  RI    RIu   RIu1    RIe  
203  1316    1/29/2010  2010.0    1.0  66.39  66.30  6.21    6.39  \
275  1316    1/29/2016  2016.0    1.0  66.97  166.84  6.89   6.32   
131  1316    1/30/2004  2004.0    1.0  66.01  66.15   6.36   6.60   
191  1316    1/30/2009  2009.0    1.0  66.36  6.54  685.25   6.71   
263  1316    1/30/2015  2015.0    1.0  66.43  6.94  114.14   6.33   
..    ...       ...      ...      ...    ...   ...     ...     ...   
250  1316   12/31/2013  2013.0   12.0  99.98   5.24    59.91   5.07   
262  1316   12/31/2014  2014.0   12.0  99.33   54.14   54.64   55.96   
274  1316   12/31/2015  2015.0   12.0  55.32   5.89    15.19  54.34   
310  1316   12/31/2018  2018.0   12.0  55.56   55.23   5.40   5.49   
322  1316   12/31/2019  2019.0   12.0  55.39   55.98   5.69   5.88  



        RIu Pct Return  RIe_Pct_Return   
203        -0.05        0.0255  \
275        -0.0358      -0.059   
131         0.058        0.05106   
191         0.0055       0.0535   
263        -0.035        0.053   
..               ...             ...   
250         0.01092       -0.05   
262        -0.001        0.02572   
274        -0.003       -0.0512   
310        -0.000       -0.05274   
322         0.004        0.039
```

This is what I got so far.

```
for DSCD in FirmReturnIndexValues['DSCD'].unique():
    secondary_df=FirmReturnIndexValues[FirmReturnIndexValues['DSCD']==DSCD]
    t=secondary_df[(secondary_df['RIe Pct Return'].values == 0)].index.values.tolist()
    t.sort()
    if len(t)>=1:
        print(np.diff((t)))
```

for example this part is t:

```
[69438, 69439, 69440, 69441, 69442, 69443, 69444, 69445, 69446, 69447, 69448, 69449, 69450, 69451, 69452, 69453, 69454, 69455, 69456, 69457, 69458, 69459, 69460, 69461, 69462, 69463, 69464, 69465, 69466, 69468, 69548, 69570, 69571, 69572, 69573, 69574, 69575, 69576, 69577, 69578, 69579, 69580, 69581, 69582, 69583, 69584, 69585, 69586, 69587, 69588, 69589, 69590, 69591, 69592, 69593, 69594, 69595, 69596, 69597, 69598, 69599, 69600, 69601, 69602, 69603, 69604, 69605, 69606, 69607, 69608, 69609, 69610, 69611, 69612, 69613, 69614, 69615, 69616, 69617, 69618, 69619, 69620, 69621, 69622, 69623, 69624, 69625, 69626, 69627, 69628, 69629, 69630, 69631, 69632, 69633, 69634, 69635, 69636, 69637, 69638, 69639, 69640, 69641, 69642, 69643, 69644, 69645, 69646, 69647, 69648, 69649, 69650, 69651, 69652, 69653, 69654, 69655, 69656, 69657, 69658]
```

this is the Indexes that I get from my code and when I use the `np.diff()` method I get this values and the values I wish to drop (delete) are being **bolded**:

> [ 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
> 1   1  1  1  1  2 80 22  1  ***1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
> 1  1  1   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
> 1  1  1  1   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
> 1  1  1  1  1   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
> 1  1  1  1  1]***

so I have 2 Questions.

1. how can I delete the bolded one's?
2. the first for loop contains 8000 DSCD's is there anyway it can be more efficient?

Another Example:
list t:

```
[74536, 74537, 74538, 74540, 74542, 74543, 74544, 74545, 74547, 74551, 74554, 74555, 74559, 74560, 74561, 74562, 74563, 74566, 74567, 74568, 74569, 74571, 74572, 74573, 74574, 74575, 74578, 74579, 74580, 74582, 74584, 74585, 74586, 74587, 74588, 74589, 74590, 74591, 74592, 74595, 74596, 74597, 74598, 74599, 74601, 74602, 74603, 74604, 74605, 74606, 74607, 74608, 74609, 74610, 74612, 74613, 74614, 74615, 74616, 74617, 74618, 74619, 74620, 74621, 74622, 74623, 74624, 74625, 74626, 74627, 74628, 74629, 74630, 74631, 74632, 74633, 74634, 74635, 74636, 74637, 74638, 74639, 74640, 74641, 74642, 74643, 74644, 74645, 74646, 74647, 74648, 74649, 74650, 74651, 74652, 74653, 74654, 74655, 74656, 74657, 74658, 74659, 74660, 74661, 74662, 74663, 74664, 74665, 74666, 74667, 74668, 74669, 74670, 74671, 74672, 74673, 74674, 74675, 74676, 74677, 74678, 74679, 74680, 74681, 74682, 74683, 74684, 74685, 74686, 74687, 74688, 74689, 74690, 74691, 74692, 74693, 74694, 74695, 74696, 74697, 74698, 74699, 74700, 74701, 74702, 74703, 74704, 74705, 74706, 74707, 74708, 74709, 74710, 74711, 74712, 74713, 74714, 74715, 74716, 74717, 74718, 74719, 74720, 74721, 74722, 74723, 74724, 74725, 74726, 74727, 74728, 74729, 74730, 74731, 74732, 74733, 74734, 74735, 74736, 74737, 74738, 74739, 74740, 74741, 74742, 74743, 74744, 74745, 74746, 74747, 74748, 74749, 74750, 74751, 74752, 74753, 74754, 74755, 74756, 74757, 74758, 74759, 74760, 74761, 74762, 74763, 74764, 74765, 74766, 74767, 74768, 74769, 74770, 74771, 74772, 74773, 74774, 74775, 74776, 74777, 74778, 74779, 74780, 74781, 74782, 74783, 74784, 74785, 74786, 74787, 74788, 74789, 74790, 74791, 74792, 74793, 74794, 74795, 74796, 74797, 74798, 74799, 74800, 74801, 74802, 74803, 74804, 74805, 74806, 74807, 74808, 74809, 74810, 74811, 74812, 74813, 74814, 74815, 74816, 74817, 74818, 74819, 74820, 74821, 74822, 74823, 74824, 74825, 74826, 74827, 74828, 74829, 74830, 74831, 74832, 74833, 74834, 74835, 74836, 74837, 74838, 74839, 74840, 74841, 74842]
```

result of `np.diff():`

> [1 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 4 3 1 4 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
> 1 3 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 **1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
> 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
> 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
> 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
> 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
> 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
> 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1**]

Hard one:

```
[6359, 6431, 6287, 6347, 6419, 6263, 6275, 6299, 6311, 6323, 6335, 6371, 6383, 6395, 6407, 6443, 6455, 6467, 6360, 6288, 6348, 6420, 6252, 6264, 6276, 6300, 6312, 6324, 6372, 6396, 6408, 6444, 6456, 6468, 6336, 6384, 6432, 6265, 6397, 6469, 6253, 6325, 6385, 6457, 6277, 6289, 6301, 6313, 6337, 6349, 6361, 6373, 6409, 6421, 6433, 6445, 6314, 6446, 6302, 6374, 6434, 6254, 6266, 6278, 6290, 6326, 6338, 6350, 6362, 6386, 6398, 6410, 6422, 6458, 6470, 6423, 6279, 6339, 6411, 6255, 6267, 6291, 6303, 6315, 6327, 6363, 6375, 6387, 6399, 6435, 6447, 6459, 6471, 6268, 6400, 6472, 6256, 6328, 6388, 6460, 6280, 6292, 6304, 6316, 6340, 6351, 6364, 6376, 6412, 6424, 6436, 6448, 6305, 6377, 6437, 6293, 6365, 6257, 6269, 6281, 6317, 6329, 6341, 6389, 6401, 6413, 6425, 6449, 6461, 6473, 6282, 6342, 6414, 6270, 6402, 6474, 6258, 6294, 6306, 6318, 6330, 6353, 6366, 6378, 6390, 6426, 6438, 6450, 6462, 6259, 6331, 6391, 6463, 6319, 6451, 6271, 6283, 6295, 6307, 6343, 6355, 6367, 6379, 6403, 6415, 6427, 6439, 6475, 6296, 6368, 6356, 6428, 6260, 6272, 6284, 6308, 6320, 6332, 6344, 6380, 6392, 6404, 6416, 6440, 6452, 6464, 6476, 6285, 6345, 6417, 6273, 6405, 6477, 6261, 6297, 6309, 6321, 6333, 6357, 6369, 6381, 6393, 6429, 6441, 6453, 6465, 6322, 6454, 6310, 6382, 6442, 6262, 6274, 6286, 6298, 6334, 6346, 6358, 6370, 6394, 6406, 6418, 6430, 6466, 6478]
```

after sorting the previous list you'll get:

> 1 **1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
> 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
> 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
> 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
> 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
> 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
> 1 1**]

as the same logic, the bold ones need to be removed

Comment: You have two questions here. would you please open another question for the looping once you have a solution that works?

Comment: What should be the result for the *Hard one*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for (Full example)

Pandas Version:

```
s = pd.Series([69438, 69439, 69440, 69441, 69442, 69443, 69444, 69445, 69446, 69447, 69448, 69449, 69450, 69451, 69452, 69453, 69454, 69455, 69456, 69457, 69458, 69459, 69460, 69461, 69462, 69463, 69464, 69465, 69466, 69468, 69548, 69570, 69571, 69572, 69573, 69574, 69575, 69576, 69577, 69578, 69579, 69580, 69581, 69582, 69583, 69584, 69585, 69586, 69587, 69588, 69589, 69590, 69591, 69592, 69593, 69594, 69595, 69596, 69597, 69598, 69599, 69600, 69601, 69602, 69603, 69604, 69605, 69606, 69607, 69608, 69609, 69610, 69611, 69612, 69613, 69614, 69615, 69616, 69617, 69618, 69619, 69620, 69621, 69622, 69623, 69624, 69625, 69626, 69627, 69628, 69629, 69630, 69631, 69632, 69633, 69634, 69635, 69636, 69637, 69638, 69639, 69640, 69641, 69642, 69643, 69644, 69645, 69646, 69647, 69648, 69649, 69650, 69651, 69652, 69653, 69654, 69655, 69656, 69657, 69658])

s[:s.index[s.diff().ne(1)][-1]+1]

returns:
[69438, 69439, 69440, 69441, 69442, 69443, 69444, 69445, 69446, 69447, 69448, 69449, 69450, 69451, 69452, 69453, 69454, 69455, 69456, 69457, 69458, 69459, 69460, 69461, 69462, 69463, 69464, 69465, 69466, 69468, 69548, 69570, 69571, 69572]
```

Logic explanation.
First diff gets to where you were.

ne(1) - only get locations where diff is not equal to 1 and then we return the indices for those points.

[-1] get the last index add 2 and then slice the original array.

Numpy Version:

```
# stay in pandas series/df and numpy arrays as much as possible avoid lists
for DSCD in FirmReturnIndexValues['DSCD'].unique():
    secondary_df=FirmReturnIndexValues[FirmReturnIndexValues['DSCD'].eq(DSCD)]
    t=secondary_df[secondary_df['RIe Pct Return'].eq(0)].index.values
    t.sort()
    if len(t)>=1:
        
        # get last index where diff is not 1
        ind = np.where(np.not_equal(np.diff(t), 1))[0][-1]
        
        # add 2 to index to remove the bolded numbers per your example
        result = t[:ind+2]
```

Answer Continued:

In general here are some simple speed ups for the code you have shown. But it is unclear what exactly you have as an input df and desire as and result. If you can provide that we can benchmark it.

```
# use direct numpy method calls (eq,lt,gt,ge,le,ne) instead of ==, <, >, etc..
secondary_df=FirmReturnIndexValues[FirmReturnIndexValues['DSCD'].eq(DSCD)]
        t=secondary_df[secondary_df['RIe Pct Return'].eq(0)].index.values  # don't convert to list if you do not need to
        t.sort()  # use numpy array sort
        if len(t)>=1:
            print(np.diff((t)))
```

These are quick wins. You likely have structural speed ups from a refactor. But you need to provide a full working example and expected output.

Comment: this is not what i wanted 
in one case this is what the series is and 


`20    751
24    752
29    754
0     755
3     756
5     757
8     758
12    759
13    760
15    761
18    762
21    763
25    764
28    765
30    766
1     767
4     768
6     769
9     770
11    771
14    772
16    773
17    774
22    775
26    776
27    777
31    778
10    782
19    786
23    787
7     793
2     899`

this is what it returned
`20    751
24    752
29    754
0     755`

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: i will provide the data in a second

Comment: you can check the data

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your problem correctly, this code will supersede the need to write a for loop and drop the unrequired data.

```
# generate a dummy dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": np.random.randint(-5,5,20)})

# index of the last 0 value
idx_end = df[df.col1 == 0]['col1'].index[-1]

# get the index of the 0 value that starts the last continuous sequence of 0 values
idx_start = df.iloc[:idx_end][df.iloc[:idx_end].col1 != 0]['col1'].index[-1] + 1

# drop data
df.drop(range(idx_start, idx_end+1), inplace=True)
```

Comment: gives me an error when i try the hard one that i have written in my Question, can you modify your code?
if this works then i'll accept it as an Answer

the Error: 
`KeyError: '[6352, 6354] not found in axis'`

Comment: Could you show me what FirmReturnIndexValues looks like (with dummy data perhaps)? I think the error you might eb because of the first filter you do for secondardy df which I haven't accounted for

Comment: i think you need to sort them because i believe that it's necessary to sort the index otherwise it doesn't make sense. i do it but unfortunately you haven't done it that's why i get other results. my code is in the Question